# Apply cloud mask to sentinel 2 image in SNAP

Tags: masking, cloud-cover, sentinel-snap

I want to apply one of the cloud masks in the sentinel 2 file to the sentinel image.

The sentinel 2 image I have downloaded features files concerning cirrus and opaque clouds at 10m, 20m and 60m.

how do I apply one of these masks to the RGB image and cancel out the clouds for future processing?

Is there a specific tool? or equation?

I am using SNAP software.

Comment: how can I do the same thing with qgis?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Raster > Mask > Land/Sea Mask

and choose `Use vector as mask` and the corresponding cloud band in the dropdown menu.

[image: masking images in SNAP]

Comment: @sineadbrack Consider to mark this as the correct answer if it helped you