# Sentinel-2 L2A cloud masking

Tags: sentinel-2, sentinel-snap, sen2cor

I have a Sentinel-2 L2A image downloaded from the Scihub.copernicus website.This image has clouds that muddle the classification. Thus, I want to remove them using sen2cor and SNAP. Is there any suggestions?

Comment: Already answered here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/230102/apply-cloud-mask-to-sentinel-2-image-in-snap?rq=1

Comment: you could use FORCE to achieve that (and much more) https://www.uni-trier.de/index.php?id=63673

Comment: With GRASS GIS (open source), you can also use the addon https://grass.osgeo.org/grass7/manuals/addons/i.sentinel.mask.html

Comment: Is there a way to do so in python? I downloaded S2-L2A which is produced by S2Cloudless, but I ended up with an empty mask each time. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

Sentinel-2 L2A products already include a cloud mask (in the "*SCL* file), produced by Sen2cor (but quite far from perfection). You do not need to apply Sen2cor again.