# How to acquire Sentinel-2 cloud mask files?

Tags: qgis, cloud-cover, scp

**BACKGROUND:**

At 3.22.12, I download Sentinel-2 files (both L1C and L2A) using the Semi-Automatic Classification (SCP) plugin.  Some of the imagery contains cloudy areas that I would like to mask out.  According to the following sources, my downloads *should* contain additional files that contain cloud masks for each image:

- According to  [Sentinel-2 L2A cloud masking](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/330113/sentinel-2-l2a-cloud-masking), "*Sentinel-2 L2A products already include a cloud mask (in the SCL file)...*"
- [Cloud masks (CLM) and cloud probabilities (CLP)](https://docs.sentinel-hub.com/api/latest/user-guides/cloud-masks/) [files?]
  can be rquested from the Sentinel Hub.
- [This SCP instructional video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xm9s97GPs0Y) shows at timestamp 7:10 that L1C downloads come with a **MSK_CLOUDS_B00.gml** vector file that acts as a cloud mask.

Unfortunately, none of my SCP downloads arrive with any such cloud mask files, even though I check the "Ancillary data" option:

[image]

The only ancillary files that are downloaded are **MTD_TL.xml**, and **MTDSIL1C.xml** (with L1C downloads) or **MTD_MSIL2A.xml** (with L2A downloads).  None of these appear to have any mask information.

**QUESTION**:

How can I acquire cloud mask files (preferably through SCP)?

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the Semi-Automatic Classification (SCP) plugin, but if you download the archive from the official [source](https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/#/home), it contains files with image classification (including cloud mask).

Download [scene](https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/odata/v1/Products(%2711ae03d6-5fe2-4cdf-97a7-2d02baf47050%27)/$value) example.

Cloud mask path:

S2B_MSIL2A_20221109T020009_N0400_R017_T52RHP_20221109T034700.SAFE\GRANULE\L2A_T52RHP_A029644_20221109T020011\QI_DATA\**MSK_CLDPRB_20m.jp2**